# .net JIT compiler quadratic on large methods

Tags: .net, il

I would like to generate a large switch statement in IL, then JIT-compile it, and run it . It seems that the JIT compiler takes time somewhat worse than quadratic in the size of the code. Doubling the input size multiplies the compilation time by a factor of between 4 and 6. The individual cases are under 10 instructions each.

Could someone please tell me if there is a way of asking the JIT compiler to take O(n^(1+epsilon)) time (E.g. linear, n log n, or something else substantially sub-quadratic)? I am not fussed about degraded quality of results.

The reason for generating an enormous switch is not important here. I can work around the issue by nesting switches. I cannot just put the keys into a dictionary because it would need to map to functions, and lots of little functions are bad for scalability too (possibly not as bad as massive switches, but it's still a pan/fire sort of a situation where blindly changing one for the other probably will not buy a huge amount of headroom).

Comment: Out of curiosity, how large is this switch statement we are talking about? And since it's generated, isn't there some commonality among cases that you can utilize to do what you need to do in a more efficient (from a compilation standpoint) way?

Comment: I need to make sure the solution is scallable, I won't necessarily be using the maximum size all the time (or ever). The largest switch I tried had 256k cases and took over an hour to compile. There is commonality between the cases, but the whole point is to pre-compute them. And yes, they are all different.

Comment: This is not unusual, the optimizer has O(n^something) complexity.  Large programs, like the jitter, a perf tuned after they are written and tested, addressing common problems that users complain about.  Some don't get addressed, generics have a O(n^big) worst case.  You can report you problem at connect.microsoft.com.  Do not expect a miracle, the perf tuning job is very likely to be yours, not theirs.

Comment: That is not surprising. I just need to know if the compiler has an option that turns the optimiser off.

Comment: It would help to know why you are trying to generate such a large piece of code. I am extremely suspicious that it is necessary. You're asking "How can I make this solution to my problem work?" when maybe you should be asking "How do I solve my problem?"

Comment: How does the generated IL look like? Are you using [the `switch` instruction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.switch)? Or just a series of tests and jumps?

Comment: If you must know, I want to evaluate a complex function. The best way I can think of is to precalculate/compile its parts. I then need to choose the appropriate pre-calculated solution. That in turn is a part of a large IL-code generator. It runs 100+ times faster than the next best alternative I have in some cases. No matter how bizarre what I do is, I think it's very reasonable to want to understand the complexity the JIT compiler. It's not like it should completely dominate the overall runtime, seeing as it's not hard to translate Il code badly and quickly. An hour for a few megs of code?

Comment: Svick: The generated code is one large switch. I haven't yet tried seeing if the compilation times depends just on the size of the whole function or if a large function with lots of local blocks would be faster.

Comment: I would guess the JITter is trying to find common sub-expressions, etc. I think it is worth attempting to convert it to a `Dictionary(Of <lookupType>, Func(Of <ParameterTypes>, <ReturnType>))` as that would also mean the JITter only compiles the cases actually used. Of course if your individual delegates end up being based upon large closures, that probably explains part of your original performance issue.

Comment: Alternatively, and to partially confirm what the JITter is doing, don't change the `switch` code, but in each case call a delegate that evaluates the result for that case. This will force the JITter to not inline the call and thus not attempt many optimisations. In fact you can probably avoid the delegate call and just supply each case in a subroutine with the `NoInlining` attribute. I would have added this as an answer, except you rule out lots of little functions.

Comment: Mark Hurd: I may well be mistaken about lots of little functions being a problem - obviously it will at initialisation time, but I can work around that. I will try your suggestion to check. Your is the most constructive answer so far, and in the absence of better suggestions I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess the JITter is trying to find common sub-expressions, etc. I think it is worth attempting to convert it to a `Dictionary(Of <lookupType>, Func(Of <ParameterTypes>, <ReturnType>))` as that would also mean the JITter only compiles the cases actually used. Of course, if your individual delegates end up being based upon large closures, that probably explains part of your original performance issue.

Alternatively, and to partially confirm what the JITter is doing, don't change the `switch` code, but in each case call a delegate that evaluates the result for that case. This will force the JITter to not inline the call and thus not attempt many optimisations. In fact, you can probably avoid the delegate call and just supply each case in a subroutine with the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)` attribute.

Comment: It turns out that common sub-expressions aren't the issue. I get the same behaviour even when each case just pushes a number and jumps to the end. The numbers are all different.

Comment: Did you give me the tick because you got no other answers, or did something I said actually helped?

Comment: It was the best answer, and then to the question I had asked :-) I think the JIT compiler gets very slow if given a lot of code, no matter what that code is. It turns out that a reasonable workaround is to just split large chunks of code into lots of smaller members, and then it just works again. Except coding it is a pain because you need to model the code fragments as nodes in a graph if you want to get the jumps right. That's probably not something you would have planned for no matter how carefully you initially thought about the problem. But it's straightforward in principle.